# What is "EC2-Other" filter in "Cost Explorer" dashboard mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

While investigating AWS Bill using Cost Explorer tool, I selected `EC2-Other` filter under services and it showed an amount around 5k monthly but I still don’t know what capabilities (features or services) are costing all this amount. What does `EC2-Other` includes in `Cost Explorer` dashboard ?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Not a programming question, but a question lots of programmers might care about (proof: upvotes)

Comment: all such AWS questions should be allowed here as Amazon own forums are so poor and Amazon needs to be shamed into addressing their forums

Answer (score 362):

There are 2 parts to your question (give a man a fish, and teach him how to fish).

1. Costs for EC2-Other include things such EBS, Data transfer, Load Balancers, etc.
2. If you'd really want to check internally what you're being charged for, go to **"Cost Explorer"**, select the monthly cost report, **filter** on the right the "EC2-Other" service, and **group by** "Usage Type"

Good luck

Comment: Good luck is the perfect way to describe exploring AWS costs haha +1

Comment: @PragmaticProgrammer yes it's baffling that with all this functionality they can't show a simple dashboard that says "this is what you're spending $$$ on"

Comment: Have you tried https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/cost/200_labs/200_cloud_intelligence/? 
This is a great way to get started on cost monitoring and KPIs

Comment: @GuillaumeRoderick I've complained officially and to be fair, things _have_ improved. It's an absolute state though, particularly for newbies!

Answer (score 147):

In order to understand **EC2-Other Costs** you'll need to get its details In **AWS Cost Explorer** > Explore Cost & Usage > in the right panel filter by **Service** and select **EC2-Other**. In the graph, group by **"usage type"**.

I present below a list with the most common EC2-Other costs, which are associated to the following services:

- EBS:VolumeUsage.gp2($)
- EBS:SnapshotUsage($)
- CPUCredits:t2/t3($)
- NatGateway-Hours($)
- DataTransfer-Regional-Bytes($)
- ElasticIP:IdleAddress($)
- NatGateway-Bytes($)
- REGION1-REGION2-AWS-Out-Bytes($)
- REGION1-REGION2-AWS-In-Bytes($)
- Others

[image]

For the detailed list in your current AWS account you can look at the list below the graph, and consider downloading the .csv file in case you need to share this info w/ your accounting/finance staff.

[image]

#### Reference Links:

- https://www.devcop.io/2018/12/12/pesky-aws-ec2-other-costs-confusion-all-around/
- https://www.itproportal.com/features/7-hidden-aws-costs-that-could-be-killing-your-budget/
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=705136

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cost-management/tips-and-tricks-for-exploring-your-data-in-aws-cost-explorer-part-2/

Comment: this is helpful but none of these links nor this post explain `NatGateway-Bytes` and where those come from

Comment: You now do not have the "Cost & Usage", so in the "Cost explorer" change the group by to dimension "Usage type"

Comment: @fIwJlxSzApHEZIl NatGatway bytes  are bytes sent from your private VPC to the internet. Consider it a bandwidth out from private network to the world. What communicates with the outside world - you have to map internally. First you need to identify the NAT used to serve the traffic, then just ask around who uses it :)

Comment: thank you! I actually had a rogue ECS container that couldn't connect to a database and it spent a lot of CPU and network cycles attempting to nonstop. It drove up the cost to hundreds of dollars in a month amazingly enough.

Comment: As it's now 2023, the method I found that works is going to 'Cost explorer' then 'Usage Type Group' as a filter option